# Site Content and Structure - Unable to move content within folders

Tags: content-and-structure

We have a list with more than 20,000 items and the items are divided into folders such as no folder has more than 4000 items.  The list works fine on it own.  We need to move some of the items using "Content and Structure" but when we go to the Content an Structure, we can see all the folders but it doesn't allow us to click within folder and see items.  The folder looks static and does not respond to clicks.

This list was working fine till last week.  There is a warning at top of the list in Content and Structure, which says "Large list context detected. Custom Views and reports may fail for this list."  This warning has been there since the list crossed 5000 items and it didn't affect us in moving items but now we are not able to go within folders in "Content and Structure" to move items within them.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a threshold concept introduced from SharePoint 2010 which limits certain features on lists/document libraries as per standard boundaries.

In order to overcome those threshold restrictions, you need to alter either via  UI/powershell.

Pls refer the below link for more details. [enter link description here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mimorr/archive/2012/08/28/disable-sharepoint-2010-list-throttling-at-the-list-level.aspx)

Comment: Hi Kesava - Thanks for your response.  Do you know if one of those limiting features is that the user cannot move/copy content in "Content and Structure" when that threshold limit is reached.  Client has divided content in folders to go around the threshold limit.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ricky, if you have noticed even though the content is segregated in to multiple folders when a view is created to show the items with out folders then the views,filters and other features will fail to behave normally due to threshold limits. so theoretically if the threshold is removed, then it should work but performance could be bad.